# What does the parameter -experimental in New-VM do?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I found the parameter `-Experimental` for the cmdlet `New-VM`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/new-vm?view=win10-ps) for `New-VM` is a little lacking there... Does anyone know what it does?

Comment: I've never seen this parameter. I'm curious too and I didn't find any kind of content about.